# Programmatically focusing on <table> element causes VoiceOver navigation to break

Tags: html-table, accessibility, voiceover, tabindex

I have a table that I am trying to make accessible and navigable by VoiceOver. On its own, the table seems to be navigable by VO, and seems compliant with most of the accessibility guidelines I've found.

The table is:

```html
<table id="menu" tabindex="0">
  <caption>Cafe menu items</caption>
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Size</th>
      <th scope="col">S</th>
      <th scope="col">M</th>
      <th scope="col">L</th>
      <th scope="col">XL</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">Coffee</td>
      <td>1.00</td>
      <td>2.00</td>
      <td>3.00</td>
      <td>4.00</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td scope="row">Frappe</td>
     <td>2.00</td>
     <td>3.00</td>
     <td>4.00</td>
     <td>5.00</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I think my main issue is how I initially put focus on this table--when a user clicks (either via mouse or via VoiceOver) a link, this menu is added to the page and the page scrolls down to it. However, when I try to navigate around the table (via VO + arrow key), it's nearly impossible-- cells are skipped over entirely, or, more frequently, I automatically am navigated outside of the table. VoiceOver will say "you are currently on a table", but when I do VO + arrow key (or even tab), I am navigated out of the table and onto another element. Sometimes, it also reads the number of columns/rows incorrectly, when it initially hits the table, as well.

When the link is clicked to open the menu, I add focus to the table with `document.getElementById('menu').focus();` and have `tabindex="0"` on the table so it receives focus. I have a feeling that's what's mucking things up in VoiceOver, but don't know how to otherwise programmatically focus on the table on click.

As I said, on its own (in the snippet), navigating the table works as expected. But navigating to it programmatically, and then navigating through it, is really messy.

Any advice/input would be much appreciated!

UPDATE: I realized the issue may be that I'm testing this in VoiceOver on Chrome, which seems to not be a very common combination per this [survey](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey7/) and maybe one that is not recommended. Everything works as it should very reliably in Safari.

Comment: try `tabindex="-1"` instead of `tabindex="0"` - never seen the behaviour you describe but if it is indeed to do with adding the table to the focus order this could fix that. `tabindex="-1"` allows you to programatically focus the table without adding it to the focus order of the page. If that works let me know and I will elaborate in an answer.

Comment: That sort of helped, but navigating inside the table, it still skips over cells about half the time. The focus seemed to land on the table more reliably, but entering INTO that table almost impossible (I did VO + arrow key and also tried tab, and was always nav'ed outside of the table to the next element on the page, and had to navigate back in to be able to navigate around the cells).

Comment: What is the reason for making the table focusable and/or give it focus ? I suspect you don't need to do it and shouldn't do it.
Depending on your case, it may be useful for cells or rows to have focus, but an entire table, I honnestly don't see any usefulness.

Comment: The thought was you click on a "see menu" link, and the page scrolls to the menu, where you should be able to navigate through the table. I wasn't sure if you could still navigate through that table without focusing on it first. Perhaps this is unnecessary, though?

Comment: Your example differs from the two headers example here https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/two-headers/ in that you've added a thead. Does removing that thead fix the keyboard navigation?

Comment: @tx291: if your table represent a menu, no, you shouldn't focus the table itself. For a menu, you should focus one of the actual selectable options. Normally the first one (or maybe the last used or the most likely one).

Comment: just to clarify, when i say "menu" I don't mean a navigational menu -- this is just a table of text describing items and prices available for purchase